# How to display current active page title in Aurelia.JS

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm using aurelia JS now. And I have a problem when aurelia start routing, I want to change the title page into current location in my body tag, exactly I mean not the `<title>` tag but the inside body
I've a dig around and search for the tutorial but until now I don't get the right answer

I attached my code

```html
<template bindable="router">
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header" mdl="layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-color--primary">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">${title}</span>
        <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="android-more-button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-ripple-effect"
                id="more-button">
          <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
        </button>
        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-js-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="more-button" mdl="menu">
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">5.0 Lollipop</li>
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">4.4 KitKat</li>
          <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">4.3 Jelly Bean</li>
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Android History</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      </div>
    </header>
```

I want my ${title} display a current active page. I have search around but not found the answer

Here my app.js code

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import {AuthorizeStep} from 'resources/AuthorizeStep';

export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';

    config.map([
      {route: ['penyakit',''], name: 'penyakit', moduleId: 'pages/penyakit/penyakit', nav: true, title: 'Beranda',settings:{icon:'dashboard',color:'teal'}},
      {route: 'penyakit', name: 'penyakit', moduleId: 'pages/penyakit/penyakit', nav: true,auth:true, title: 'Penyakit',settings:{icon:'inbox',color:'blue'}},
      {route : ['penyakit/tambah','penyakit/edit/:id'], name : 'tambah_penyakit' , moduleId : 'pages/penyakit/tambah_penyakit',nav:false,auth: true,title:'Tambah Penyakit'},
      {route: 'gejala', name: 'gejala', moduleId: 'pages/gejala/gejala', nav: true, title: 'Gejala',settings:{icon:'event notes',color:'orange'}},
      {route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: 'pages/user/users', nav: true, title: 'Aturan CF',settings:{icon:'layers',color:'green'}},
      {route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: 'pages/user/users', nav: true, title: 'divider',settings:{icon:'description'}},
      {route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: 'pages/user/users', nav: true, title: 'Pengaturan',settings:{icon:'settings',color:'grey'}},
    ]);
    config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);

    this.router = router;
  }

  change_app_bar_color(color)
  {
    var app_bar = $('#app_bar');
    app_bar.removeClass('blue-inbox teal orange green grey');
    app_bar.addClass(color);
    console.log('F');
  }
}
```

Comment: Describe your problem with sample code please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour and visit the help center. There you'll learn that your question is too broad/unclear to be answered. If you share what you have tried we might be able to help.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I have attached the code

Comment: @DhiaTN sorry I am a new member here, still learn to write a good question and learn my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `currentInstruction.config.title` of the router object:

```
this.router.currentInstruction.config.title;
```

Remember that you might have to bind the router to the web component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but I want in my <!-- Title --><span class="mdl-layout-title">${title}</span> the ${title} always change when aurelia start routing. Exactly I mean change into current active page title not the Document Title

Comment: I've test into my code and now my <span class="mdl-layout-title">${this.router.currentInstruction.title}</span> but it doesn't show anything. it's my app.html and I wrong place the code

Comment: try just `${router.currentInstruction.config.title}`. Without the "this"

Comment: just same as previous.The title was empty result.Can u give me another code.

Comment: I've attached in my question

Comment: did you try to navigate to a route? I tested the code here, and it works fine. Every time I navigate to a route, the title updates on the screen

Comment: I'm really sorry.Your code is running when I tested , the problem is my gulp doesn't update the code.When I running gulp watch again. The Title updated on the screen.Thanks man.